# Are Java System.in/out/err always open?

Tags: java, io, system.out, system.in, system.err

Javadoc says `in`, `out` and `err` are 'already open', I just wonder that do they close after program finishes? If not does it contradict the practise to close any I/O stream references after use?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure.  I certainly would expect all streams to be closed on exit (think of a JVM that is part of a pipe, it's got to signal end of input/output), but what happens if the JVM exits with an error?  If the error is severe enough I'm sure that streams won't be flushed and closed, it's always possible to lose data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are very much a Unix concept, but other operating systems (such as Windows) have copied the concept as well. These are maintained by the system, and you usually don't close them.

However, you *can* close them, and you even *have* to close them when you `fork()` a program, which is the Unix way to have a program detach from the command line and run in the background, such as a daemon.

`System.in`/`out`/`err` follow this strategy. So you could close them, but you don't have to, because they're special system resources.

Answer (score 1):

System.in / out / err these classes are Instantiated by the JVM, not by us.
Hence JVM will take care of closing them.

Comment: That said, it *is* possible to close them.

Comment: Yes, It is possible to close them manually but not necessary to do this.